# Google Maps won't show up

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm working on a project which involves a "Points of Interest" locator. I have a generated Google Maps API v2 key and I've added all the proper permissions to the AndroidManifest (as you'll see below), and everything compiles...except for the map itself! There's a marker that shows your current location and as well as the GPS coordinates but not the map, which needless to say is essential. Also there are no runtime erros except that the LogCat says at points "There is too much output to process". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Android Manifest**

```
    package="com.example.kavin_000.travelapplication" >
    <!-- suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.kavin_000.travelapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.kavin_000.travelapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/nyit_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ow_main_page"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".manhattan_main_page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manhattan_main_page" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main_page"
            android:label="Travel Application" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ow_campus_points_of_interest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ow_campus_points_of_interest" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".manhattan_campus_points_of_interest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manhattan_campus_points_of_interest" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_KEY" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ow_main_page"
    android:background="#ffffb502">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latlongLocation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff058fff"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java class in question**

```
package com.example.kavin_000.travelapplication;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class ow_campus_points_of_interest extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GooglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ow_campus_points_of_interest);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there may be an issue with your authorization on Google App Engine. Did you make sure to use the SHA1 fingerprint from your **debug.keystore** and not from your release keystore? Additionally, make sure that you are appending `;com.example.kavin_000.travelapplication` to the end of the SHA1 fingerprint.

If you have not added your SHA1 fingerprint to the list of authorized applications, that is the issue. It can be done by finding your `debug.keystore` file (search on Google depending on your OS), and running the following command:

`keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore`

Comment: Wow, I was going to redo the whole key too but I trusted myself too much to type in the SHA-1 fingerprint correctly the first time without double checking, thanks!